# Is a list from a subquery modifiable?

Tags: apex, soql

I am trying to modify a list of sobjects that I get from a subquery but it appears that adds to the list are simply silently ignored. sample code:

```
Account acc = [select ID, (select ID from Contacts limit 1) from Account limit 1];
Integer consize = acc.contacts.size();
acc.contacts.add(new Contact(lastname='test'));
system.assertequals(consize+1,acc.contacts.size());
```

Is this expected behaviour? I might be misremembering but I could swear I've done this in the past.

**UPDATE**: Setting acc.contacts directly will also not work as you get the following error:

```
Field is not writeable: Contacts
```

If you assign acc.contacts to a list you can then work with the list as normal but this is not ideal for my use case as I have a function that I want to return a list of sobjects with 1-n subqueries.

**UPDATE 2**: It appears that you can modify the properties of the sobjects in the list, just not the list itself.

```
Account acc = [select ID, (select ID from Contacts limit 1) from Account limit 1];
list<Contact> con1 = acc.contacts;
con1.get(0).lastname = 'TEST';
system.assertequals('TEST',acc.contacts.get(0).lastname);

list<Contact> con2 = acc.contacts.clone();
con1.get(0).lastname = 'TEST2';
system.assertequals('TEST2',acc.contacts.get(0).lastname);
```

Comment: `System.assert(acc.contacts === acc.contacts);` fails, so you never have access to the actual underlying list reference.  I don't see it documented anywhere that a cloned copy is what to expect for a child list, but it would be consistent with trying to keep the list from not being writable. Likewise `acc.contacts.remove` has no effect.

Comment: This is a real curiosity and not what I expected. Even if I pass the list to a new variable, it is not writable. That being said, I've also never tried it this way, I always associate new related records by assigning an id to the related ID field. Maybe this is in place to prevent someone adding the contact but *not* assigning the AccountId value?

Comment: @PeterKnolle didn't even know there was an exact equality operator in apex. If you run this in dev console with apex FINEST you can see that everytime you assign acc.contacts to a list it is creating a new reference (different memory address) so it definitely appears to be cloning it behind the scenes.

Comment: @PeterKnolle What is really odd is that even though it gives a new memory address each time you assign the list every object in the list still has the same references. (code above)

Comment: @PeterKnolle I think we've basically proved that it is making a clone of the list behind the scenes whenever you get the sub-query. You can go ahead and post that as the answer if you'd like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`System.assert(acc.contacts === acc.contacts);` fails, so you never have access to the actual underlying list reference.  Each time there is a call to `acc.contacts` a different `List<Contact>` is created and returned.

I don't see it documented anywhere that a cloned copy is what to expect for a child list, but it would be consistent with trying to keep the list from not being writable. Likewise `acc.contacts.remove` has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

That's pretty strange that modifications to the list aren't stored by reference, kudos for figuring out that it's regenerated each time you access it.  Can't think of any good reason why they'd do it that way.

You'll want to work with them as a list created from your query object.  I don't know your exact use case, but keeping them in the account.contacts list isn't going to be useful for updating even if you could modify the list.  Changes made to non-query objects (subqueries and parent objects) are ignored in update calls (i.e. `account.owner.lastName = 'asdf'` would be stored in memory but not committed if you updated the acccount).

If you're trying to keep things grouped for display this might work well for you.

```
public Class AccountGroup {
  public Account account { get; set; }
  public List<Contact> contacts { get; set; }

  public AccountGroup(Account account) {
    this.account = account;
    contacts = account.contacts;
  }
}
```